# using trello api to check if board has changed?

Tags: python, api, trello

I am making a script that checks if a trello board has been changed,

this is my first time working with any api in general.

```
import requests
import json

url = "url" #I have deleted the url, key and token for obvious reasons

query = {
   'key': "key",
   'token': "token"
}


response = requests.request(
   "GET",
   url,
   params=query
)  

last_request = json.load("Last_request.json")
if last_request != response.text:
   print("change")

with open("Last_request.json", "w") as outfile:
   outfile.write(response.text)
```

everything is working it gets the correct board, and it should not be printing change but it always does.

the problem is that the code in the if statement is being called when the if statement should be false.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: `response.text` is just text, but `last_request` is the result of `json.load()`, so it's going to be some python object (probably a dictionary).  Of course those two things aren't equal.